# Is it correct to write 'to + Verb ing'

Tags: verbs

I studied verbs followed by to and verbs followed by ing on British Council Learn English website and Cambridge Dictionary's Grammar section; however I don't know this construction is it a mistake?

> It is vital that we also remember that cultural stereotypes can be detrimental to building good business relationships.

It's from a C1 reading text from BC Learn English page. Is it correct to write to+verb ing? What is the rule and/or the convention?

Comment: Short answer: *building* in this sentence is a noun, meaning "the act of building".  It's a noun created from a verb, but it is still a noun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*to* can be the marker of the *to-infinitive*, but it can also be a preposition.

Some words require a *to-infinitive* clause:

> I want **to go** home

Some words require an *-ing* clause:

> I enjoy **playing** the piano

Some words can accept either:

> I like **playing/to play** the piano.

Some words take a noun-phrase complement introduced by the preposition *to*:

> That dust is detrimental **to** my health.

And that noun phrase can often be an *-ing* clause:

> Cultural stereotypes can be detrimental **to** building good business
> relationships.

So yes, it can be grammatical to have *to* followed by an *-ing*, when the *to* is a preposition.